# Visual Studio 2015/C#: Automatically rename all namespaces in project to match directory structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, namespaces, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I want to fix my namespaces of a large solution containing several projects that got a bit messed up after copying and refactoring some UserControls...

My goal is simply that all namespaces match the folder structure a file is located in. There's always only one namespace per file.

How could I achieve this? I already know how to change a project's root namespace, but that's not what I need here.

*Example:*

The file `...\Project1\OneDirectory\Subdirectory\Code.cs` contains the

```
namespace Project1.OtherDirectory.Subdirectory { /* ... */ }
```

This should get refactored to:

```
namespace Project1.OneDirectory.Subdirectory { /* ... */ }
```

---

**Additional candy:**

Reorganize `using` statements as well, so that unused namespaces are no longer included, but add those who changed and remove explicit namespace identifiers.

*Example:*

```
var c = new Project1.OneDirectory.Subdirectory.Code();
```

should become

```
using Project1.OneDirectory.Subdirectory;
/* ... */
var c = Code();
```

Comment: [Use Resharper's "Adjust Namespaces" feature.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html). (If you don't already have Resharper then... you should ;)